# What is swig-wx?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i know what swig is, but what is swig-wx exactly and why do i need this when i want to compile ros?

swig-wx version 1.3.29 (2006)

swig version 2.0.7  (2012)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37602/what-is-swig-wx?/) by [mano](https://answers.ros.org/users/2635/mano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2012-07-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for your quick answer!

I found this on the swig-wx site (https://github.com/wg-debs/swig-wx/blob/master/stack.xml):

*This is a special version of swig needed by wxPython, which is SWIG version 1.3.29 plus some custom patches (explained at http://wxpython.org/builddoc.php). The patched latest version of wxPython SWIG is available at http://wxpython.wxcommunity.com/tools*

> ... under the Install graphical library dependencies section of the install guide).

Is there a general installation guide which lists the dependencies?

---

Originally posted by [mano](https://answers.ros.org/users/2635/mano/) with karma: 141 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2012-07-02**:
It's generally considered to be bad form to ask additional questions in posting an answer. If you did not intend for this to be posted as an answer to your own question, it would be better to move it into your original question and delete this answer post.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the [wxWidgets site](http://www.wxwidgets.org/):

> wxWidgets is a C++ library that lets developers create applications for Windows, OS X, Linux and UNIX on 32-bit and 64-bit architectures as well as several mobile platforms including Windows Mobile, iPhone SDK and embedded GTK+.

And also:

> It has popular language bindings for Python, Perl, Ruby and many other languages.

From the [SWIG site](http://www.swig.org/):

> SWIG is a software development tool that connects programs written in C and C++ with a variety of high-level programming languages.

Combining this: `swig-wx` provides bindings to wxWidgets for the languages used in ROS. Using these bindings, various tools in ROS are able to provide a graphical user interface.

So this package is needed in order to be able to build (and run) the tools that use the toolkit for their UIs (which is also why it is mentioned under the *Install graphical library dependencies* section of the install guide).

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-07-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2